Emacs 29.4 on Windows: GLib-GIO warnings when closing
I recently installed Emacs 29.4.0.20240806 on Windows using Chocolatey. When I close Emacs using C-x C-c, I receive the following warnings:
(process:18124): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 06:39:18.517: Unexpectedly, UWP app `Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_1.2023.727.100_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe' (AUMId `Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.OutlookforWindows') supports 1 extensions but has no verbs
(process:18124): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 06:39:19.060: Unexpectedly, UWP app `Files_3.7.6.0_x64__1y0xx7n9077q4' (AUMId `Files_1y0xx7n9077q4!App') supports 6 extensions but has no verbs

Installation Details
I installed Emacs using the following Chocolatey command:
choco install Emacs -y

The installation completed successfully, deploying Emacs to C:\tools\emacs.
Questions

What do these GLib-GIO warnings mean?
Are these warnings affecting Emacs functionality?
How can I diagnose the root cause of these warnings?
Is there a way to resolve or suppress these warnings?

Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.
